# How to access an Objective-C class method from an instance in Swift

Tags: ios

If there is Objective-C code like this:

```objective-c
@protocol MyProtocol
@required
+ (void)aClassMethod;
- (void)anInstanceMethod;
@end

@interface MyClass <MyProtocol>
@end

@implementation MyClass
+(void)aClassMethod {
}
-(void)anInstanceMethod {
}
@end
```

And have only the following available in Swift:

```swift
func myFunc(obj: MyProtocol) {
  // want to access aClassMethod here
}
```

Then how can I access `aClassMethod` on `obj`?

--edit--

Some clarification on what I'm trying to achieve. Let's throw in another class:

```
@interface AnotherClass <MyProtocol>
@end

@implementation AnotherClass
+(void)aClassMethod {
    // Here I'm doing something different than in MyClass
}
-(void)anInstanceMethod {
}
@end
```

And then in Swift, if I have this:

```
let a = MyClass()
let b = AnotherClass()
myFunc(a)
myFunc(b)
```

I want `myFunc` to be able to call `aClassMethod` on the object it receives.

Reason: I'm creating classes to serve as models to store data. Each model class has a string name, which is the same for each instance, hence the class method. I pass around these instances, but I want their names, to put inside a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
func myFunc(obj: MyProtocol) {
    object_getClass(obj).aClassMethod()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You're trying to call a class method from an instance of this same class, which is not possible**. Instead you can either call`MyClass.aClassMethod()` or `obj.anInstanceMethod()`.

> MyClass() acts as an initializer. When using it, you're creating a new instance of your class on which you can only use instance methods.

Comment: So I need to get access to `MyClass` from `obj`. Something like `obj.self`... is that possible in Swift?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Which operation would you like to perform on its class? You can check the class with `obj.dynamicType === MyClass.self`.

Comment: Added some clarification to the question, hope this makes it clear